# It’s hard to admit that

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Isn't the phrase ***It’s hard to admit that ...*** ambiguous?

For instance: *It’s hard to admit that the sight of these umbrella-wielding infocrats hurrying by, radiating self-importance, strikes me as some kind of affirmation of the human spirit.*

What's the meaning after all? *It's hard to admit* (to myself) that this is so, or *it's hard to admit* because this isn't so at all (kind of sarcasm)?

Comment: "Sharply dressed executives, bankers and databrokers stride past me; people who could easily work from their homes, who could operate entirely within their own skulls — and even, with the help of mods, choose to enjoy it. It's hard to admit that the sight of these umbrella-wielding infocrats hurrying by, radiating self-importance, strikes me as some kind of affirmation of the human spirit. The light suddenly dims, and I look up to see two layers of churning grey cloud racing each other across the sky. Seconds later, I'm drenched." Greg Egan, _Quarantine_.

Comment: But other people probably don't. And the context might help them answer your question.

Comment: I have a problem with starting the sentence with "it." Why not say, "I find hard to admit that the sight of these . . .."

Comment: *It's hard to admit* is usually a concession that one's former opinion was wrong.

Comment: It's hard to admit that your comment does entirely exclude a possibility of sarcastic reading :)

Comment: @MvLog Whether the concession is sincere or sarcastic must be gleaned from context. But, well played!

Answer (score 3):

*"It's hard to admit..."* is not usually used sarcastically - it would be too confusing.

It is simply a self-effacing acknowledgement that one's thoughts or reactions to something are contradictory to what one thought one believed - or, *should* believe.

Answer (score 0):

it's entirely context-dependent. in one context, "I love you" is a sincere expression of devotion. In another, it's an expression of deep hatred.  ambiguity like this is a permanent feature of human language.